# Exposing WCF as RESTful

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

I'm trying to follow the blog post *[Using a REST WCF Service](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/02/using-rest-wcf-service.html)*.

But I don't know where the Global.asax page is. Is it important to add that bit from the blog?

Also when I try to connect from my [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application with the below code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ChannelFactory<ServiceReference1.IService1> factory = new
        ChannelFactory<ServiceReference1.IService1>(
            new WebHttpBinding(),
            "http://localhost:8000/Hello"))
            {
                factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
                var helloService = factory.CreateChannel();
                label1.Text = helloService.GetData(Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text));
                // The above line
            }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Could not connect to http://localhost:8000/Hello/GetData. TCP error
code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine
actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8000.
```

My Web.Config file from my other project which is the host looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService2.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService2.Service1Behavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:29174/Service1.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService2.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService2.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This is my host which I disabled and just ran the wcfservice alone:

```
namespace Host
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            WebServiceHost host =
            new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1),
            binding,
            "http://localhost:8000/Hello");

            host.Open(); // this line gives an error
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world service");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <RETURN> to end service");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run this I get this error related to the blog and my `web.config` file:

> This service requires ASP.NET compatibility and must be hosted in IIS.
>   Either host the service in IIS with ASP.NET compatibility turned on in
>   web.config or set the
>   AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute.AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode
>   property to a value other than Required.

I tryed commenting that part out in my configuration file but then it wouldn't run. This may explain why I can't connect with my Windows Forms application.

Note however in my `web.config` file and in the code below `AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute.AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode` both are set:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(string value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

Comment: global.asax maybe?  A for App, C for Control

Comment: And 8000 != 29174, ask your mailman.

Comment: Yes Global.asax dont know what your second comment means tho.

Comment: @Garrith: Your port numbers have to match in both the client and service configuration.

Comment: I have added the service using "add new webservice" so the client app is auto set.

Comment: the only thing I havent added is the route request as I dont see any global.asax file in my service application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you are looking at assumes you are making an ASP.NET web application, hosted in [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services), which would have a `Global.asax` file.

Since you are hosting it in a console application, you don't have this file, nor would it do anything if you put one there.

---

Also, in your configuration you have:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:29174/Service1.svc"
```

but in your code,

```
"http://localhost:8000/Hello"
```

Which is very different.

---

The error you receive on startup of you console application states:

> This service requires ASP.NET compatibility and must be hosted in IIS. Either host the service in IIS with ASP.NET compatibility turned on in web.config or set the AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute.AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode property to a value **other than Required**.

But your code has that property set to **Required**. A console application can not provide ASP.NET compatibility mode, only a real web server like IIS or [Cassini](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893391) or [IIS Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services#IIS_Express) can provide that. Hence you get an error when it is set to *Required*. You could try setting it to a different value, other than *Required*, as the error message suggests. However, certain other things might not work correctly without ASP.NET Compatibility mode.

---

The best thing to do would be to re-do your work here as an ASP.NET Web Application, unless you actually plan on making a real-life project that has to be run as a console application or [Windows service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service).

Answer (score 2):

The global.asax page is a page that is found on [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) websites. It acts kind of like the bootstrapper of the webpage. When the webpage first spins up, it performs all of the startup actions (in this case wiring the service URL as a route, but I am not sure exactly on the specifics as I have never used that route personally).

As to your error, it might be from your configuration. It seems to be pointing to `localhost:29174`, yet your error is coming from `localhost:8000`. I am not sure if that is your issue or not. But, you might also want to try it with your firewall off and see what happens, as it could be your firewall blocking the call.

Comment: sorry scroll along in the code I pasted I set the localhost to that. The service is hosted on 29174

Comment: Give me a second I need to update the question, see the last time I was hosting from a console app but that itself gives an error! so i just ran the wcfservice without it.

Comment: Updated my question just not sure whats going on at all.

Comment: @Garrith That error seems to be covered by the 2nd and 3rd snippets of code in the blog article, FYI.

Comment: yup its in both my service and web config (check the top of the web.config and I will post the code aswell for myservice)

Comment: if I set it to Allowed, if I then launch my windows app I get The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.